# What are the benefits of css selector syntax with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

When using css selectors to find elements, you can write them in several ways.  For example:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("header.top-bar.js-top-bar._fixed"));
```

vs

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("header[class='top-bar js-top-bar _fixed']"));
```

and

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("form[id='search'][action='/search']"));
```

vs

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("form#search[action='/search']"));
```

---

For me it's just a personal preferences using one over the other, but I was wondering if there are any performance benefits in using for example:

`header.top-bar.js-top-bar._fixed` vs `header[class='top-bar js-top-bar _fixed']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "CSS Test Creator" which lets you test the speed of different CSS selectors:

http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/csscreate.php

I tested both tag.class and tag[class='class'] using 10,000 rules and 10,000 anchors. Running each test 5 times, I got the following results:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
|  Test #  | tag.class|tag[class|
+----------+-----------+----------+
|    1     |  226 ms  |  177 ms |
|    2     |  197 ms  |  211 ms |
|    3     |  228 ms  |  177 ms |
|    4     |  207 ms  |  200 ms |
|    5     |  209 ms  |  198 ms |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|  AVERAGE |  213 ms  |  192 ms |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Based on the above inference its safe to say that tag[class='class'] has better performance than tag.class

Comment: Thanks for testing this and providing the link, how did you perform the actual test?